# Difference between "safe from" vs "safe of" something

Tags: prepositions, compound-adjectives

When indicating that something is secured from something dangerous it is possible to say that it is safe from something. For example, you might say

> Properly kept farm animals are safe from predators.

However, is it possible to also use the preposition "of"?

> Properly kept farm animals are safe of predators.

According to Google "safe from" is way more popular. From [freedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/safe) I found one definition

> (2) safe - (of an undertaking) secure from risk.

which suggests "safe of" might be correct as well.

Is saying "safe of predators" okay, improper style, perhaps has a different meaning, or simply wrong?

Comment: Any combination is words is possible, but while "safe of" would likely be understood by most people it sounds wrong. The dictionary reference you quote isn't saying "safe of".

Comment: ... No. As nnnnnn (I hope I've spelled that correctly) implies, << 2. safe - (of an undertaking) secure from risk. .. is short for << 2. safe - (when you are speaking / thinking of an undertaking) secure from risk. // Please add correct supporting evidence, or list dictionaries not licensing (this doesn't necessarily mean mandating against) the string  'safe of N'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be improper to use the preposition "of" with "safe". I believe the "(of an undertaking)" is indicating that, for that definition, "safe" is an adjective describing "an undertaking". E.g. "Playing with blocks is safe."